# How to stop a variable from changing it's value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write an animation so that, when clicked, jQuery will record that objects position relative to the browser window in a variable (projectPosition), then move it somewhere else and set it as "open". If it is clicked again, it will move back to it's original position, as recorded in the variable and mark it as closed.

The problem is, I'm declaring this variable in the event, but that means it gets redeclared when it's clicked again, overwriting the value of it's original position. I tried declaring the variable in the if statement so that it would only be set when the project is clicked and closed, but then it's value is not accessible from the else if.

Is there a way to have jQuery hold the value set from when it was marked as closed? Here's the code:

```
$(".projectContainer").click(function(){
    var projectPosition = $(this).offset();;
    var selProject = (this);
    if (!projectOpen){
        $(".projectContainer").not(this).fadeOut(200,"swing",function(){
            $(selProject).animate({
                left:'0px',
                top:'80px',
                width:'100vw'},600,"easeOutQuint");
        });     
        projectOpen = true;
    }
    else if (projectOpen){
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            left:'projectPosition.left',
            top:'projectPosition.top',
            width:'384px'},400,"swing",function(){
                $(".projectContainer").not(this).fadeIn(200);
            });
        projectOpen = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, you are using a local variable which exists only till the event handler is exited. Declare the variable in a outside scope, also the value assignment should happen only in the `if` block

```
var projectPosition;
$(".projectContainer").click(function () {
    var selProject = (this);
    if (!projectOpen) {
        projectPosition = $(this).offset();;
        $(".projectContainer").not(this).fadeOut(200, "swing", function () {
            $(selProject).animate({
                left: '0px',
                top: '80px',
                width: '100vw'
            }, 600, "easeOutQuint");
        });
        projectOpen = true;
    } else if (projectOpen) {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({
            left: projectPosition.left,
            top: projectPosition.top,
            width: '384px'
        }, 400, "swing", function () {
            $(".projectContainer").not(this).fadeIn(200);
        });
        projectOpen = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Argh, this is one of those situations where I swear I had tried that option and it didn't work for some unforeseen reason, but lo and behold, I just tried it, and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
if(typeof(variable) != "undefined" && variable !== null) {
     //Write to variable because item wasn't clicked.
}
```

So once the variable is set, it wont be set again when clicked again because its not "undefined" and not "null".